# Неправильный формат даты в С++ QT

Tags: qt, c++

```
fileINfo->lastModified().toString("dd.MMM.yyyy") //14.???.2013
```

Должно быть 14.Jan.2013

Comment: может не **dd-MMM-yyyy**, а **dd-MM-yyyy**?

Comment: @DreamChild в этом случае я получаю месац как число, а нужно как строку с 3 символов.

Comment: lastModified() это точно datetime? Должно работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По документации месяц возвращается согласно QLocale::system(). Уверены, что у вас английский в системе?